# android: keepscreenon and status bar artefacts

Tags: android, screen

I use keepscreenon to keep the samsung tab 4 screen from dimming and it works. But after 20-30 mins, the status bar starts to get weird artefacts. Like certain parts will turn different colors. Pretty weird.

Is there a way to refresh/redraw the status bar, or whole screen...which may get rid of it? Or anyone else have any insight as to the cause or solution?

BTW the status bar color is black. I had previously tried red and thought the color was the problem, so I changed to black but issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

well the only way I could figure to do this was to make a seperate thread, running once a minute whereby I would set the color of the status bar. That ends up getting rid of the artefacts. Interesting I only saw this problem on lollipop (not kitkat), but more than 1 tablet.

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#1f8234"));
        }
```